# Vectorizing a polar coordinate conversion loop in a fingerprint-matching process

Tags: coordinate-system, iteration, matlab, vectorization

I am working on a fingerprint matching technique and it takes a lot of computation time to obtain the result. I am trying to implement the matching process given in [*A Minutia Matching Algorithm in Fingerprint Verification*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/ICPR.2000.903046). I would like to know if there is any method available to reduce the `for` loop for this code:

```
[Tdrow,Tdcol]=size(Td);
[Idrow,Idcol]=size(Id);
matchingscore=zeros(Tdrow,Idrow);
rv = bsxfun(@minus,Td(:,3),permute(Id(:,3),[2 1]));
%convert each minutiae point to polar coordinates with respect to the
%reference minutiae in each case
for i=1:Tdrow
    for j=1:Idrow
        Tdp=zeros(Tdrow,Tdcol);
        Idp=zeros(Idrow,Idcol);
        tref=Td(i,:);
        iref=Id(j,:);
        Tdp(:,1)=sqrt((Td(:,1)-tref(1)).^2 + (Td(:,2)-tref(2)).^2);
        Tdp(:,2)=mod(atan2(tref(1)-Td(:,1),Td(:,2)-tref(2)) * 180/pi,360);
        Tdp(:,3)=mod(Td(:,3)-tref(3),360);
        Tdp(:,4)=Td(:,4);
        Idp(:,1)=sqrt((Id(:,1)-iref(1)).^2 + (Id(:,2)-iref(2)).^2);
        Idp(:,2)=mod((atan2(iref(1)-Id(:,1),Id(:,2)-iref(2)) * 180/pi) + rv(i,j),360);
        Idp(:,3)=mod(Id(:,3)-iref(3),360);
        Idp(:,4)=Id(:,4);
        Tdp1 {i,j}= Tdp(:,:);
        Idp1 {i,j}= Idp(:,:);
    end
end
```

Here, the variable `Td` is the fingerprint template to be compared and `Id` is the input fingerprint template. Both `Td` and `Id` have four columns, i.e. 1st and 2nd column provide x and y coordinate respectively, 3rd column is the angle and 4th column is the type of minutiae. `Tdp` and `Idp` are calculated using the equation provided in the attachment provided in the link.

Can this code be vectorized? I understand that the indexes have hardly been used. But without changing the index i cannot continue to the further steps. It would be very helpful is anyone could provide me with any suggestions.

The data values are available on [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3IeQ-na-m9rX1pNWDM2Qlo0cjA/view?usp=sharing). These has both the input data and output data.

Comment: You would be more likely to get an answer if you provided some sample input, expected output, and an explanation, so that we don't need to reverse-engineer your code. Note that MathJax is available.

Comment: @200_success I have attached the data values.

Comment: I struggle a bit reading this code... Not because it is bad, but because `T` and `I` look so similar. Is it correct that it takes about 2-3 seconds, when it's not warmed up? Are you running this code many times in a row in a loop, or is it a one time thing? If it's a process you're doing manually, then your time is probably best spent working on some other part of your project. Relevant [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1205/).

Comment: @stewie. Thank you for taking a look at it. But yes it runs in a loop several times. But it turns out my input to this section was sometimes 1000x4 matrix. But it shouldn't have exceeded 80x4. This code works good now.

Comment: (This is a year and a half after the fact, blame Jamal for editing old posts...) Don't do this `Tdp1{i,j}= Tdp(:,:);`. Do this instead `Tdp1{i,j}= Tdp;`. I don't know how clever the MATLAB interpreter is, but it's likely expensive redundancy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said your code works good, as the input isn't too big, so I won't go ahead an try to vectorize this. So, I've provided a general review of the code.

Overall your code looks nice. You should however attempt to have a bit more spaces

```
[Tdrow, Tdcol] = size(Td);  <-- This
[Tdrow,Tdcol]=size(Td);     <-- Not this
```

There are only a few things I would do differently in the code:

1. You can speed this up quite a bit even without vectorization: The size of the cells `Tdp1` and `Idp1` are known, so these cells can be [pre-allocated](https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/66550) in front of the loop:

   ```
   [Tdp1{1:Tdrow, 1:Idrow}] = zeros(Tdrow, Tdcol);
   [Idp1{1:Tdrow, 1:Idrow}] = zeros(Idrow, Idcol);
   ```

   This way you avoid creating `Tdrow*Idrow` arrays inside the loop. That should save you some time.
2. `Tdp(:,:)` is the same as just `Tdp`, so you can do:

   ```
   Tdp1{ii,jj} = Tdp;
   ```
3. Note,  `ii` and `jj` are better than [`i` and `j` as iterator names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab) in Matlab.
4. You are converting angles from radians to degrees a few places `atan2(x,y) * 180 / pi`. Instead, use [`atan2d(x,y)`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/atan2d.html). It returns the value in degrees directly.

Answer (score 0):

Without trying to understand your code too much, it's obvious that your double loop needs to be a single loop. This is the code inside the loop:

```
        tref=Td(i,:);
        iref=Id(j,:);
```

Here you extract `tref` and `iref`, which depend in `i` and `j`, respectively. Then you compute:

```
        Tdp(:,1)=sqrt((Td(:,1)-tref(1)).^2 + (Td(:,2)-tref(2)).^2);
        Tdp(:,2)=mod(atan2(tref(1)-Td(:,1),Td(:,2)-tref(2)) * 180/pi,360);
        Tdp(:,3)=mod(Td(:,3)-tref(3),360);
        Tdp(:,4)=Td(:,4);
```

This part does not depend on `j` or in `iref`. This should not be inside the loop over `j`. Next you compute:

```
        Idp(:,1)=sqrt((Id(:,1)-iref(1)).^2 + (Id(:,2)-iref(2)).^2);
        Idp(:,2)=mod((atan2(iref(1)-Id(:,1),Id(:,2)-iref(2)) * 180/pi) + rv(i,j),360);
        Idp(:,3)=mod(Id(:,3)-iref(3),360);
        Idp(:,4)=Id(:,4);
```

This part does not dpeend on `tref` or `i`, nor on `Tdp`. This should not be inside the loop over `i`.

Thus your code reduces to:

```
[Tdrow,Tdcol]=size(Td);
[Idrow,Idcol]=size(Id);
rv = bsxfun(@minus,Td(:,3),permute(Id(:,3),[2 1]));
for i=1:Tdrow
  Tdp=zeros(Tdrow,Tdcol);
  tref=Td(i,:);
  Tdp(:,1)=sqrt((Td(:,1)-tref(1)).^2 + (Td(:,2)-tref(2)).^2);
  Tdp(:,2)=mod(atan2(tref(1)-Td(:,1),Td(:,2)-tref(2)) * 180/pi,360);
  Tdp(:,3)=mod(Td(:,3)-tref(3),360);
  Tdp(:,4)=Td(:,4);
  Tdp1{i,:}=Tdp;
end
for j=1:Idrow
  Idp=zeros(Idrow,Idcol);
  iref=Id(j,:);
  Idp(:,1)=sqrt((Id(:,1)-iref(1)).^2 + (Id(:,2)-iref(2)).^2);
  Idp(:,2)=mod((atan2(iref(1)-Id(:,1),Id(:,2)-iref(2)) * 180/pi) + rv(i,j),360);
  Idp(:,3)=mod(Id(:,3)-iref(3),360);
  Idp(:,4)=Id(:,4);
  Idp1{:,j}=Idp;
end
```

And once you do that you notice the symmetry of the problem, you only need to write one of these loops, and re-use it by reversing the inputs.

Weird though, that you are never comparing `Id` to `Td`. What does this code do? And why do you need to populate `Tdp1` and `Idp1` with repeated arrays?

Are you sure this code is correct?

Using longer names would simplify things: `Id` becomes `input`, `Td` becomes `template`, etc. It would make it a lot easier to spot issues, since `I` and `T` look so much alike.